# Does C# have implicitly-named parameters for the Lambda syntax similar to Swift?

Tags: c#, swift, lambda, closures

In Swift, the concept of closures is closely synonymous to lambda expressions in C#. Using an example where there's a function `foo()` (`Foo()` in C# due to different standardized naming rules) that takes in a lambda/closure which has two parameters, you can write them like this...

C#:

```
Foo( (a, b) => a + b );
```

Swift:

```
foo{ a, b in a + b };
```

However, Swift can also implicitly name those variables...

```swift
foo{ $0 + $1 };
```

Note that there is no `in` in that statement.  The compiler confirms that if there are two parameters required, then you have to have both `$0` and `$1`.  If there were three parameters, it would also require `$2`.

I'm wondering if C# has anything similar where the parameters are implicitly defined.

Comment: As of C#8, there is no such similar support.

Comment: @user2864740, can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as such? Otherwise this'll just sit open, or I'll have to answer my own question and you won't get those shiny new ten points!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't something similar in C# (as of C# 8).